# How to fix Elixir Phoenix Render Error per online Tutorial

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm doing the basic getting started tutorial at the Elixir Phoenix website: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/request_lifecycle.html

I followed the instructions for creating a basic page via:

- route
- controller
- view
- template

I got the following error:

```
Could not render "index.html" for HelloWeb.HelloView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "lib/hello_web/templates/hello/*". No templates were compiled for this module. Assigns:
```

I went over my code multiple times and as far as I can tell I did exactly as the instructions asked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I commented out the route I made and ran the server. I got a completely different error. Now the server won't start.

**EDIT:**

I realize the below error is saying the server port is being used. I am not sure why that happened, nor why the error doesn't say "Port already in use" like a sane person would say.

[image]

**EDIT**

After changing the server port, running my router/controller/view/template code -  everything works.
I have no idea why the hell this all happened. I'll leave this post up just in case someone else runs into the same thing. I think Phoenix needs simpler error reporting.

Comment: The ranch error has nothing to do with phoenix, the error is cryptic because the library got optimized, the error message will be fixed in next versions. As for the template error, there is a bug in the file watcher, where sometimes the templates will not get compiled automatically, you just have to restart the server.

Comment: I got the error again building a new route per the phoenix tutorial. Restarting did not fix it this time

Comment: Confirming I got the same error, and changing the default server port from 4000 solved it. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that you have a zombie process on your http server and when its try to start detect that something its already running on that port.

Make sure kill the server with the process pid, something like

kill -9 pid_number and then try to re-run the proyect.